# Text classification: value error couldn't convert str to float

Tags: scikit-learn, word-embedding

Input for random forest classifier trained model for text classification

I am not able to know what should be the input for the trained model after opening the model from the pickle file.

```
with open('text_classifier', 'rb') as training_model:
    model = pickle.load(training_model)
for message in text:
    message1 = [str(message)]
    pred = model.predict(message1)
    list.append(pred)
return list
```

**Expected output:** Non political

**Actual output :**

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RT @ScotNational The
>   witness admitted that not all damage inflicted on police cars was
>   caused

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the text as numbers. No machine algorithm can process text directly.

More precisely, you need to use a word embedding (the same used for training the model). Example of common word embeddings are Word2vec, TF-IDF.

I suggest you to play with `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer` and `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer` to familiarize yourself with the concept of embedding.

However, if you do not use the same embedding as the one used to train the model you load, there is no way you will obtain good results.

Comment: thank you sir can i get a link which will help me for the same